# Error while executing lua with scrapy_splash which fails with 400 and says "Required argument is missing: lua_source"

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Here's my code:

```
def start_requests(self):
            headers = {
                "method": "GET",
                "path": "/",
                "scheme": "https",
                "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
                "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "accept-language": "en-GB,en;q=0.7",
                "cache-control":" max-age=0",
                "sec-ch-ua":' "Brave";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"',
                "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
                "sec-ch-ua-platform": "macOS",
                "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
                "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
                "sec-fetch-site": "none",
                "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
                "sec-gpc": 1,
                "upgrade-insecure-requests": 1,
                "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            }
            script = '''
        function main(splash, args)
         assert(splash:go(args.url))
            local load_all_cards = splash:jsfunc([[
                function () {
                    const anchorBtn = document.querySelector("#listing-load-more a");
                    const displayBtn = document.getElementById("listing-load-more");

                    function clickAnchorBtnUntilNone() {
                        if (displayBtn.style.display === "none") {
                            clearInterval(intervalId);
                            console.log("Display button is now none.");
                            return;
                        }
                        anchorBtn.click();
                        console.log("Clicked anchor button.");
                    }

                    const intervalId = setInterval(clickAnchorBtnUntilNone, 500);
                }
            ]])
             load_all_cards()
             return splash:html()
        end
        '''
        
            yield SplashRequest(self.url, self.parse,endpoint='execute',args={'url': self.url, 'lua_source': script,'http_method': 'GET','wait': 0.5, }, headers=headers )

def parse(self, response):
        print(response)
       # Want to capture HTML here to target elements and scrape their values
```

Here's my `settings.py` configuration

```
BOT_NAME = "eventscraper"

SPIDER_MODULES = ["eventscraper.spiders"]
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = "eventscraper.spiders"
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = "2.7"
TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = "utf-8"

SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.59.103:8050'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25 # 250 ms of delay
```

Here's my error:

```
2023-05-28 15:55:01.369076 [events] {"path": "/execute", "rendertime": 0.0030176639556884766, "maxrss": 452452, "load": [0.01, 0.02, 0.0], "fds": 53, "active": 0, "qsize": 0, "_id": 279797553360, "method": "GET", "timestamp": 1685289301, "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", "args": {}, "status_code": 400, "client_ip": "172.17.0.1", "error": {"error": 400, "type": "BadOption", "description": "Incorrect HTTP API arguments", "info": {"type": "argument_required", "argument": "lua_source", "description": "Required argument is missing: lua_source"}}}
2023-05-28 15:55:01.372181 [-] "172.17.0.1" - - [28/May/2023:15:55:00 +0000] "GET /execute HTTP/1.1" 400 207 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-05-28 15:55:50.824800 [-] Timing out client: IPv4Address(type='TCP', host='172.17.0.1', port=63988)
2023-05-28 15:56:01.378371 [-] Timing out client: IPv4Address(type='TCP', host='172.17.0.1', port=63986)
2023-05-28 16:17:56.758467 [events] {"path": "/execute", "rendertime": 1.960496425628662, "maxrss": 452452, "load": [0.03, 0.02, 0.0], "fds": 55, "active": 0, "qsize": 0, "_id": 279797765960, "method": "POST", "timestamp": 1685290676, "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", "args": {"cookies": [], "headers": {"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.7", "Authority": "www.mello.fun", "Cache-Control": " max-age=0", "Method": "GET", "Path": "/", "Scheme": "https", "Sec-Ch-Ua": " \"Brave\";v=\"113\", \"Chromium\";v=\"113\", \"Not-A.Brand\";v=\"24\"", "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0", "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "macOS", "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document", "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate", "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none", "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1", "Sec-Gpc": "1", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}, "http_method": "GET", "lua_source": "\n        function main(splash, args)\n         assert(splash:go(args.url))\n            local load_all_cards = splash:jsfunc([[\n                function () {\n                    const anchorBtn = document.querySelector(\"#listing-load-more a\");\n                    const displayBtn = document.getElementById(\"listing-load-more\");\n\n                    function clickAnchorBtnUntilNone() {\n                        if (displayBtn.style.display === \"none\") {\n                            clearInterval(intervalId);\n                            console.log(\"Display button is now none.\");\n                            return;\n                        }\n                        anchorBtn.click();\n                        console.log(\"Clicked anchor button.\");\n                    }\n\n                    const intervalId = setInterval(clickAnchorBtnUntilNone, 500);\n                }\n            ]])\n             load_all_cards()\n             return splash:html()\n        end\n        ", "url": "https://www.mello.fun/", "wait": 0.5, "uid": 279797765960}, "status_code": 200, "client_ip": "172.17.0.1"}
2023-05-28 16:17:56.759718 [-] "172.17.0.1" - - [28/May/2023:16:17:55 +0000] "POST /execute HTTP/1.1" 200 169713 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

I've also tried having the script on class level and accessing it through `self.script`. What i want to achieve is load the site, render html, find the selector button which reveals more cards when clicked, keep clicking it till all cards are there on the screen and then get list of all the cards. but i am unable to figure out how to render the html and then capture it in parse method

Comment: unable to figure out what am i missing in the configuration to make this work. Also,  I am new to python and scraping so, sorry already if it's a dumb question! I'd be grateful for any help that you provide